# Convert Objective-C to Swift Date Label

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6, nsdate

I am working on an app, and trying to achieve a different text label message based on the day of week. ex. if

Monday: "Today's Hours are: 8:00am - 6:00pm"
Tuesday: "Today's Hours are: 8:00am - 6:00pm"
Wednesday: "Today's Hours are: 8:00am - 6:00pm"
Thursday: "Today's Hours are: 8:00am - 6:00pm"
Friday: "Today's Hours are: 8:00am - 6:00pm"
Saturday: "Today's Hours are: 9:00am - 2:00pm"
Sunday: "Sorry we are closed today"

My Objective-C Code that works is:

```
NSDate* currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeZone* currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSTimeZone* nowTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:currentDate];
NSInteger nowGMTOffset = [nowTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:currentDate];

NSTimeInterval interval = nowGMTOffset - currentGMTOffset;
NSDate* nowDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:currentDate];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
NSString *dayName = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nowDate];

NSString *timing = @"8:00am - 6:00pm";
NSString *description =@"Today's Hours are";
NSArray *days = @[@"Monday",@"Tuesday",@"Wednesday",@"Thursday",@"Friday",@"Saturday",@"Sunday",];

for (NSString *str in days) {
    if ([str isEqualToString:@"Saturday"]) {
        timing = @"9:00am - 2:00pm";
    }
    if ([str isEqualToString:@"Sunday"]) {
        description = @"Sorry we are closed today";
        timing = nil;
    }
    if ([str isEqualToString:dayName]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ : %@ :%@",str,description,timing);
        //here you can write yourLabelname.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@ :%@",str,description,timing];
    }
}
```

Can I get help on converting this to Swift?

Comment: SO is not a code translation service. Try writing the method in Swift yourself and then ask specific questions on what is causing you difficulty.

Comment: Btw: Your timezone/offset juggling looks suspiciously complicated, what are you trying to achieve with that? – And your method to determine the current weekday works only in the english locale. On my computer, `dayName` would be "Montag", "Dienstag", ... Better learn how to work with NSDateComponents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write code in Swift which was originally written in objective-c it's quite easy. Most of the times the methods names are the same as in objective-c. [In this Developer Library you can get many informations about that.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/)

But to give you a little idea how similar the methods are:

```
var currentDate:NSDate = NSDate()
var currentTimeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")

var nowTimeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

var currentGMTOffset = currentTimeZone?.secondsFromGMTForDate(currentDate)
var nowGMTOffset = nowTimeZone.secondsFromGMTForDate(currentDate)

var interval:NSTimeInterval = Double(nowGMTOffset) - Double(currentGMTOffset!)

var nowDate = NSDate(timeInterval: interval, sinceDate: currentDate)

var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"

var dayName = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(nowDate)

var timing = "8:00am - 6:00pm"
var description = "Today's Hours are"
var days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday", "Sunday"]

for str in days{
    if(str == "Saturday"){
        timing = "9:00am - 2:00pm"
    }

    if(str == "Sunday"){
        description = "Sorry we are closed today"
    }

    if(str == dayName){
        println("\(str) : \(description) : \(timing)")
    }
}
```